# Errors while attempting to install Python 2.7.13 and 3.5.2 on Windows

Tags: python

I have been trying to install either *Python 2.7.13* and *3.5.2* on *Windows 64*-bits. I continue to get the following error:

```
Error writing file: C:\Python27\tcl\tcl8.5\encoding\ascii.enc. 
Verify that you have access to that directory.
```

I have tried EVERYTHING suggested on Google search outcomes, including trying to install it in a drive other than `C`, running `chkdsk` at boot time,and many other suggestions. I verify that I have full access to the directory. I also tried the installation as Administrator. Nothing works for me.

Can someone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Installing Python 2.7.11 on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252585/error-installing-python-2-7-11-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your c drive and checking the security settings. Make sure you have full rights to it. Then go to your accounts in control panel and make sure you are an admin.

You can also go into the directory and try to save a txt document to see if you have permissions.