# Why does repair python return "Can't write to file" even though i have access to the specified directory?

Tags: python, windows, python-install

Something python-related wasn't working properly (sadly don't remember what), so I ran the "Repair python" tool, but about halfway it returned:

```
"Error writing to file:"
   C:\Users\nicke\AppData\local\programs\Python\38-32\python38.dll
```

Verify that you have access to that directory"

I can manually navigate (EDIT: and add new files) to that directory, which i assume means that I do have access.

[image: screenshot of error message]

"Prøv på nytt" means retry, and "avbryt" means cancel.

Comment: Can you create new files in that directory? That's the relevant "access" here.

Comment: Yes I can do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Installer: "Error writing to file C:\Python27\pythonw.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252585/python-installer-error-writing-to-file-c-python27-pythonw-exe)

Comment: Yes it did thank you!